# Opening a new window (JFrame) with e.getsource

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am having a problem with opening a new window. If I comment out the if(e.getsource() == btnAddBook) the action performed opens the window. As soon as I add the if statement in and try to open the window, nothing happens.

```
 /* this is the code that adds the button and the action listner

    JButton btnAddBook = new JButton("Add Book");
            btnAddBook.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 8));
            btnAddBook.setBounds(10, 327, 86, 23);
            btnAddBook.addActionListener(this);
            getContentPane().add(btnAddBook);
    */

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if(source == btnAddBook){
    ChildWindowAdd child = new ChildWindowAdd(this);
    this.setVisible(true);
    child.setVisible(true);
    child.setSize(450,400);     
    child.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
  }
}

class ChildWindowAdd extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        LibraryDatabase parent;
        Container c;
        JLabel lblTitle, lblaName, lblISBN, lblDate,lbl1,lbl5,lbl10;
        JTextField txtTitle, txtaName, txtISBN, txtDate;
        JButton btnSave;
        JSlider sRating;
        JCheckBox chkSci, chkFant, chkRomance, chkAction, chkThriller, chkHorror;


        public ChildWindowAdd(LibraryDatabase parent){
            this.parent = parent;
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);

            txtTitle = new JTextField();
            txtTitle.setBounds(46, 29, 146, 20);
            getContentPane().add(txtTitle);
            txtTitle.setColumns(10);

            JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("Book Title");
            lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
            lblTitle.setBounds(36, 11, 72, 14);
            getContentPane().add(lblTitle);

            JLabel lblaName = new JLabel("Author Name");
            lblaName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
            lblaName.setBounds(36, 60, 89, 14);
            getContentPane().add(lblaName);

            txtaName = new JTextField();
            txtaName.setBounds(46, 85, 146, 20);
            getContentPane().add(txtaName);
            txtaName.setColumns(10);

            JLabel lblIsbnNumber = new JLabel("ISBN Number");
            lblIsbnNumber.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
            lblIsbnNumber.setBounds(36, 116, 86, 14);
            getContentPane().add(lblIsbnNumber);

            txtISBN = new JTextField();
            txtISBN .setBounds(46, 143, 146, 20);
            getContentPane().add(txtISBN );
            txtISBN .setColumns(10);

            JLabel lblDate = new JLabel("Date Added yyyy/mm/dd");
            lblDate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
            lblDate.setBounds(36, 174, 177, 20);
            getContentPane().add(lblDate);

            txtDate = new JTextField();
            txtDate.setBounds(46, 199, 146, 20);
            getContentPane().add(txtDate);
            txtDate.setColumns(10);

            JPanel genreP = new JPanel();
            genreP.setBounds(239, 29, 158, 194);
            genreP.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Genre's", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
            getContentPane().add(genreP);
            genreP.setLayout(null);

            final JCheckBox chkSci = new JCheckBox("Sci - Fi");
            chkSci.setBounds(23, 22, 97, 23);
            genreP.add(chkSci);

            final JCheckBox chkFant = new JCheckBox("Fantasy");
            chkFant.setBounds(23, 48, 97, 23);
            genreP.add(chkFant);

            final JCheckBox chkRomance = new JCheckBox("Romance");
            chkRomance.setBounds(23, 74, 97, 23);
            genreP.add(chkRomance);

            final JCheckBox chkAction = new JCheckBox("Action");
            chkAction.setBounds(23, 100, 97, 23);
            genreP.add(chkAction);

            final JCheckBox chkThriller = new JCheckBox("Thriller");
            chkThriller.setBounds(23, 126, 97, 23);
            genreP.add(chkThriller);

            final JCheckBox chkHorror = new JCheckBox("Horror");
            chkHorror.setBounds(23, 152, 97, 23);
            genreP.add(chkHorror);

            final JSlider sRating = new JSlider();
            sRating.setBounds(118, 280, 200, 26);
            getContentPane().add(sRating);

            JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("1");
            lbl1.setBounds(118, 257, 7, 14);
            getContentPane().add(lbl1);

            JLabel lbl10 = new JLabel("10");
            lbl10.setBounds(301, 257, 17, 14);
            getContentPane().add(lbl10);

            JLabel lbl5 = new JLabel("5");
            lbl5.setBounds(214, 257, 7, 14);
            getContentPane().add(lbl5);

            JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save Book");
            btnSave.addActionListener(this);
            btnSave.setBounds(164, 317, 110, 23);
            getContentPane().add(btnSave);

            JLabel lblRating = new JLabel("Rate the book");
            lblRating.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            lblRating.setBounds(118, 226, 95, 20);
            getContentPane().add(lblRating);

            btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    PrintWriter fileWriter = null;
                    try {
                        fileWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\temp\\database.dat", true)));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    fileWriter.println( txtTitle.getText()+" , "+txtaName.getText()+" , "+txtISBN.getText()+" , "+txtDate.getText()+" , "+String.valueOf(chkSci.isSelected())+" , "+String.valueOf(chkFant.isSelected())+" , "+String.valueOf(chkRomance.isSelected())+" , "+String.valueOf(chkAction.isSelected())+" , "+String.valueOf(chkThriller.isSelected())+" , "+String.valueOf(chkHorror.isSelected())+" , "+sRating.getValue());
                    fileWriter.close();
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            parent.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }

    public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




    }
```

Comment: Where have you added `ActionListener`? Have you called `btnAddBook.addActionListener()` any where?

Comment: to the btnAddBook button

Comment: If you've associated the listener with just one button, why do you need to check the source?

Comment: Please share that portion of code where you have added it.

Comment: try this one `System.out.print(source.getClass().getName());` to find out the source object class name.

Comment: there is other buttons Duncan so I am trying to call this button specifically. Also, i added the button code in

Comment: Braj, that outputted Javax.swing.JButton

Comment: You shouldn't test for event source objects in `actionPerformed`. Use an `actionCommand` to decouple the action and the GUI element. Or use `javax.swing.Action` objects. Of course it should work, somehow, even the way you do it. But you debug things that don't need to be debugged.

Comment: can you show your complete ChildWindowAdd ?

Comment: i.e. `btnAddBook.setActionCommand("openwindow"); [...] if (e.getActionCommand().equals("openwindow")) { [...]`.

Comment: Try `((JButton)source).getText().equals("Add Book")`

Comment: That outputs add book

Comment: Yes, it is getting the add book as an action performed.

Comment: If its working then use it.

Comment: put that in the if statement you mean?

Comment: I put it in the if statement and that worked.. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I have posted it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on the basis of button text

```
((JButton)source).getText().equals("Add Book")
```

---

here is complete code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if (source instanceof JButton && ((JButton) source).getText().equals("Add Book")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I had to match the String as the e.getsource was not working.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object source = e.getSource();          
            String test = ((JButton)source).getText();

            if(test == "Add Book"){
            ChildWindowAdd child = new ChildWindowAdd(this);
            this.setVisible(true);
            child.setVisible(true);
            child.setSize(450,400);     
            child.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            }
```

Comment: I have posted it already. There is one more issue in your answer. You are not checking for instanceof `JButton` that can create problem if you are using same action listener for other components also other than `JButton`.

Comment: What are you doing? Don't use `==` to compare the strings.

Comment: Use `equals()` to compare the strings contents.